# Python: How to check if ANY item of my list is contained within my string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
list = ["1", "2", "3"]
string=  abc1def
```

How can I check if ANY items of my list is contained within my string?

Comment: You can just check each member in a loop, but may find a more efficient mechanism from creating a generator and calling `next()` to only get the first match if you have a great many members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
any(substr in string for substr in list_)
```